# HTML Why is the content of an Iframe loaded twice?

Tags: html, iframe

In my application I use a javascript function to set the src tag of an Iframe:

```
function loadDocument(id, doc) {
    $("#DocumentContent").show();
    $("#ButtonBox").show();

    // Clear dynamic menu items
    $("#DynamicMenuContent").html("");
    $("#PageContent").html("");

    // Load document in frame
    $("#iframeDocument").attr("src", 'ViewDoc.aspx?id=' + id + '&doc=' + doc + '');

    // Load menu items
    $("#DynamicMenuContent").load("ShowButtons.aspx");

    // Set document title
    $("#documentTitle").load("GetDocumentInfo.aspx?p=title");
}
```

When I open Fiddler and debug this page, I notice that the 'ViewDoc.aspx' page is called twice.

When I put an alert() in the loadDocument function, I get only one alert message. In my viewdoc.aspx page there are no refresh or redirect statements or other statements that refreshes the page.

Is it possible this has something to do with browser? Is this default browser behavior?

Comment: Are you doing anything else with the `#iFrameDocument` node, e.g. moving it within the DOM?

Comment: No, I don't move the iframe. However, some functions hide and show the iframe. But this happens only on click events

Comment: @Mart hiding and showing should be okay as long as it's using CSS. Only if you remove an IFRAME from the DOM and re-insert it, I think at least IE will do a reload.

Comment: No that's not what I'm doing. I use jquery functions hide() and show().

Comment: can you verify if your function loadDocument gets called twice or if it'S just the 'ViewDoc.aspx'?

Comment: loadDocument is called once and 'ViewDoc.aspx' is loaded twice

Comment: Does iframeDocument contain any src by default? Comment line where you are loading iframe. Any changes?

Comment: I have an iframe with pdf content. I notice that the MVC controller in the src invokes twice in IE/Edge. I have read other places this may relate to an initial check for mime type. I know this is old, but if someone stumbles by it, maybe this will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is pretty old, but....

do you have two elements with id=DynamicMenuContent ?

if there's one in the source page and one in the iframe, they may both be selected by $("#DynamicMenuContent").load...

if this is true and one is a div and the other a span, you could change it to $("div#DynamicMenuContent").load()...

hth